# React components loaded before calculations are finished

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, react-functional-component

Dears
I am working on React project and currently struggling with small problem.
what is an issue ? When app is loading on a mobile view I see that all components are showing and after few ms unneeded data disappear. I would like to modify my app to display only needed components.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import RegistrationInputSide from "./../RegistrationInputSide/RegistrationInputSide";
import AppInfoSide from "./../AppInfoSide/AppInfoSide";
import SuccessWindow from "./../SuccessWindow/SuccessWindow";
import { names, labels, types} from "./registrationFormData";


const FormStyle = styled.div.attrs(({ className }) => ({
  className,
}))`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  .fields {
    display: ${({ fieldsVisibility }) => (fieldsVisibility ? "flex" : "none")};
  }
  .info {
    display: ${({ infoVisibility }) => (infoVisibility ? "flex" : "none")};
  }
`;

const RegistrationForm = ({user, onChange, validation, onSubmit, formCorrectness, formModified}) => {
  const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false);
  const [isMoved, setIsMoved] = useState(false);
  const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);
  const {password, repeatedPassword, email } = user;
  const {emailValidation, passwordValidation, repeatedPasswordValidation} = validation;


  const calculateMobileVisibility = (form) => {
    const {name, isMobile} = form;
    const visibilityRequirements = {
      "info": [{"isMobile":true, "isMoved":false, "isModified":false, "formCorrectness": false}],
      "fields": [{"isMobile":true, "isMoved":true, "isModified":false, "formCorrectness": false},{"isMobile":true, "isMoved":false, "isModified":true, "formCorrectness": false}, {"isMobile":true, "isMoved":true, "isModified":true, "formCorrectness": false}],
      "success": [{"isMobile":true, "isMoved":true, "isModified":false, "formCorrectness": true},{"isMobile":true, "isMoved":false, "isModified":true, "formCorrectness": true}, {"isMobile":true, "isMoved":true, "isModified":true, "formCorrectness": true}]
    }

    if(isMobile === false){
      return true;
    }

    const requirements = visibilityRequirements[name];
    delete form.name;

    let resultArr = requirements.map(requirement => {return Object.keys(form).map(formItem => requirement[formItem] === form[formItem])});

    const finalArr = resultArr.map(singleRes => singleRes.every((val) => val === true));

    return finalArr.includes(true);
  };


  const calculateInfoSideVisiblity = () => {
    return calculateMobileVisibility({"isMobile":isMobile, "isMoved": isMoved, "isModified": formModified ,"formCorrectness": formCorrectness, "name": "info"});
  }

  const calculateFieldsSideVisibility = () => {
    return calculateMobileVisibility({"isMobile":isMobile, "isMoved": isMoved, "isModified": formModified ,"formCorrectness": formCorrectness, "name": "fields"});
  }

  const onClickHandleMobile = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setIsMoved(true);
  };

  const handleResize = () => {
    window.visualViewport.width > 576 ? setIsMobile(false) : setIsMobile(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if(firstRender===true){
      handleResize();
      setFirstRender(false);
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    };
  });

  return (
    <FormStyle fieldsVisibility={calculateFieldsSideVisibility()} infoVisibility={calculateInfoSideVisiblity()}>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <AppInfoSide
          className="form-info-side info"
          onClick={onClickHandleMobile}
        />
        {!formCorrectness && (<RegistrationInputSide
          className="form-user-input-side fields"
          inputFieldsData={inputFieldsData}
          onClick={onSubmit}
          onChange={onChange}
          user={user}
        />)}
        {formCorrectness && (<SuccessWindow
          className="success-window fields"
          successMessage="Account successfully created!"
        />)}
      </form>
    </FormStyle>
  );
};
```

I do not know how to prevent displaying unwanted elements.

Comment: It would help if you pointed out which elements are causing problem, so that everyone wouldn't have to look it up from all of your code you posted.

Comment: What is this `formCorrectness` you refer to?

Comment: Hmm mainly I think about those three elements AppInfoSide, SuccessWindow, RegistrationInputSide. What is an issue -> all elements appear when page is rendered and after computing for styledComponents is done proper ones are shown. formCorectness is bool value and telling if success windows shall be shown or not :)

Comment: I've tried for several minutes and failed to understand your logic :) I'm not surprised that compiler doesn't either :) You can start your simplification with refqctoring to smaller functions and getting rid of those neverending lines of chained functions...

Comment: K. to be more accurate with what I wanted to say. File is compiling correctly, I do not have any errors. The issue is that probably react want to render 2 components for mobile where only one is needed. I think that it is caused by styled components, because react renders and then styled components receiving values...

Comment: Your conditional rendering depends only on `formCorrectness` prop, so you should check if it's not being modified elsewhere (outside RegistrationForm component)

Comment: Visibility of elements also depends on fieldsVisibility and inputVisibility which are passed to styled components